# Adb Run Bash script in background and exit terminal

Tags: android, adb

i have this script that wake up some service because my android os kill them every 10min 
we can do nothing about it!!!, any app that not system app is well be killed after 10mn 
the problem is i have to remain the cmd open every time i lunch this script

```
#!bin/sh

while true

do

am startservice com.app/.MainActivity

sleep 5

am startservice com.app2/.MainActivity

sleep 600

done
```

Is it possible to launch a Bash script and exit exit terminal and NOT interrupt script?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32192417/1778421

Comment: thank you but i get this error and also the nohup is not reconised as system command!!!!!!
The specified path was not found.
'' 'is not recognized as an internal command
or external, an executable program or a batch file.

Comment: thanks @AlexP. 
it working now after changing (') whit double quot