# ADB process blocks when starting background process ADVANCED

Tags: android, bash, shell, adb

So I was reading this post on how to run sleep in background via ADB shell:
[ADB process blocks when starting background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191174/adb-process-blocks-when-starting-background-process)

There is something more advanced I want to do with this, where I want to get the pid of the sleep process running in background - I want to see if this is possible via a one line command or passing this all in a script that I can call. However, every time I attempt to do it, it hangs.

So what I have in a script is:

```
sleep 100 &
echo $!;
```

this is stored in /data/local/tmp/script.sh

If I run this script in the shell itself, it works just fine:

```
adb -s <DEVICE> shell
y2q:/ $ sh /data/local/tmp/script.sh
12009
$
```

But if I do the following:
`adb -s <DEVICE> shell sh /data/local/tmp/script.sh`

it returns the pid but it hangs until the sleep finishes. Is there a way to do this command WITHOUT it blocking on the sleep? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `script` should be like this

```
#! /system/bin/sh

sleep 100 </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
echo $!
```

do `chmod +x script` and you don't need the `.sh` extension.

Then

```
adb shell /data/local/tmp/script
```

would work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Your script should be

```
sleep 100 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null & 
echo $!;
```

2>/dev/null: errors output to null

1>/dev/null: standard output to null